# Re-deploy webapplication static files in JBoss

Tags: jboss

I'm building a webapp that has some static (css, js) files.
When I make a change to a static file, I use Maven to build the war:
    mvn package

It builds a war inside the folder .\myapp\target and JBoss is configured to scan that folder:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
    <deployment-scanner path="myapp\target" scan-interval="500"/>
</subsystem>
```

and to deploy again the whole war file.
This is slowing me a lot. I'd like to just update the single static file.
I thought about copy the single file to the JBoss app directory, but the directory seems to change everytime a deploy has been done. For instance, the current directory is:

```
C:\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\tempeb183309b18f4c94\myapp.war-d4f03640093af40b\css\myawesome.css
```

There's any way to speeup the deploy of static files?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any solution to this problem. I'm currently using this workaround:

```
@echo off
FOR /F " tokens=*" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /od C:\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp') DO (SET temp_dir=%%i)
FOR /F " tokens=*" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /od C:\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\%temp_dir%') DO (SET app_dir=%%i)

echo App directory: C:\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\%temp_dir%\%app_dir%

xcopy /E /I /Y ..\src\main\webapp\css C:\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\%temp_dir%\%app_dir%\css
xcopy /E /I /Y ..\src\main\webapp\js C:\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\%temp_dir%\%app_dir%\js
```

I get the last created temp webapp directory by JBoss and just copy the files in there.